# how to run in a given time using while loop in C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, intervals

This is the given condition and I have problem with setting time interval

Find prime numbers from 2 in 5 minutes:

```
include <time.h>

end= start = (unsigned)time(NULL);

while((end-start)<300)
```

find primes

print the prime number and how many primes are there(frequency)

```
end = (unsigned)time(NULL);
```

print total execution time

And this is the code I did.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <time.h> 

int main()
{   
time_t end, start;
    
end = start = (unsigned)time(NULL);
int i, j;
int freq = 0;
int count = 0;

while ((end-start) < 300) {
    for (i = 2;; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                count = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!count) {
            ++freq;
        }
        count = 0;
    }
    return i, freq;
    printf("Prime number: %d, frequency: %d\n", i, freq);
}
end = (unsigned)time(NULL);
printf("total time : %d seconds\n", end);

return 0;
```

}

I checked the finding prime part and the frequency part was fine when I put this way`

```
        }
        count = 0;
        printf("Prime number: %d, frequency: %d\n", i, freq);

    }
    return i, freq;`
```

but there's no result even after the 5 minutes

Comment: You have to update the `end` variable with the current time inside the loop.

Comment: What is purpose of `return i, freq;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while cycle ends when according to the value of `end` and `start` 5 minutes passed. They are initialized with the same value.

`end` is **never** updated inside the loop, so this will be an infinite cycle. You update `end` **after** the loop, but that is too late. You need to update it at each step, like:

```
while ((end-start) < 300) {
    for (i = 2;(end-start) < 300; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                count = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!count) {
            ++freq;
        }
        count = 0;
        end = (unsigned)time(NULL);    printf("Prime number: %d, frequency: %d\n", i, freq);
    }
    //Don't return at this point
    //return i, freq;
}
```